# PHP Write To Text File

Tags: php, text-files

When I write to text file , all data printed on first line , although I used PHP_EOL , I want to print it line by line.

```
            $file_Name = './textFilesData/Accounts_Deafult_Data.txt';
            $current = file_get_contents($file_Name);
            $c = 0;

            while ( $c < 5 )
                {
                    $current = 'Rafat';
                    $current = $current.PHP_EOL;    

                    $c++;
                }
            file_put_contents($file_Name, $current);
```

Comment: are you reading and writing from the same file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `\r\n` should work

```
$file_Name = './textFilesData/Accounts_Deafult_Data.txt';
            $current = file_get_contents($file_Name);
            $c = 0;

            while ( $c < 5 )
                {
                    $current .= 'Rafat'."\r\n";    

                    $c++;
                }
            file_put_contents($file_Name, $current);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use:** `$current = "$current1\n";`

```
  $file_Name = './textFilesData/Accounts_Deafult_Data.txt';
            $current = file_get_contents($file_Name);
            $c = 0;

            while ( $c < 5 )
                {
                    $current1 = 'Rafat';
                    $current .= "\n$current1";    

                    $c++;
                }
            file_put_contents($file_Name, $current);
```

Comment: I Used it , but still the same @Ahosan Karim Asik

Comment: some editor  new line text showed as a single line. example windows default notepad views as single line. but have a new line into the text file.  to see actual view u can use notepad ++

Comment: Yes , This is true . Thanks @Ahosan Karim Asik

Comment: @Rafat Haj Ali  or u can use `\r\n`  for new line. but to explode line remember that..

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
$current .= "Rafat";
```